# Issues reading .pptx table

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I am reading a .pptx file, iterating through each slide and picking out specific cells on each slide, in this example, cells (x,2) and (y,3).

I wrote a cool C# app to do this, below. The tables I have made below are purely an example of what is on each slide.

Slide 1 table:

```
Part | Number | Desc |
XYZ  | 12     | temp |
ABC  | 99     | temp |
QRS  | 73     | temp |
```

Slide 2 table:

```
Part | Number | Desc |
TOB  | 24     | temp |
```

Slide 3 table:

```
Part | Number | Desc |
COX  | 24     | temp |
MOG  | 11     | temp |
```

Code to read each ppt slide:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string filePath = @"C:\Users\Is\For\Me\test.pptx";
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application PowerPoint_App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations multi_presentations = PowerPoint_App.Presentations;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = multi_presentations.Open(filePath, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
    string presentation_textforParent = "";
    var slidesCount = presentation.Slides.Count;
    for (int slideIndex = 1; slideIndex <= slidesCount; slideIndex++)
    {
        var slide = presentation.Slides[slideIndex];
        Console.WriteLine(slideIndex);
        foreach (var item in slide.Shapes)
        {
            var shape = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Shape)item;
            if (shape.HasTable == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < shape.Table.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var part_numb = shape.Table.Cell(i, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                        var part_desc = shape.Table.Cell(i, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text;
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}", part_numb, part_desc));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    while (true)
        continue;
}
```

Which gives me the output:

```
1 // slide index 1
12 temp
99 temp
73 temp
2 // slide index 2
3 // slide index 3
24 temp
11 temp
```

As you can see, slide 2 is just ignored, my question would be why is this occuring? Am I starting my for loop (with the shape.Table.Rows.Count) incorrectly? I changed the `i = 1` to `i = 0` and I had the same success as above. Not sure where my troubles are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems like it was my for loop, for some reason when i changed the loop from

`int slideIndex= 1; slideIndex < slidesCount; slideIndex++` to `int slideIndex= 1; slideIndex <= slidesCount; slideIndex++` it gave me expected output